# Using wildcard in Custom event pattern for the S3 event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

I want to send an SQS notification from an S3 bucket on a specific folder but seems wildcards are not supported in EventBridge as well as S3 Event Notification. Is there any way by which I can trigger my SQS.
BucketName: my-s3-bucket
want to send notification if file added in a specific folder inside this bucket:

```
MyFolder/<username>/INPUT/abc.txt
```

and not on any other folder inside this bucket.
I tried EventBridge as well by below event but no luck there as well:

```
 {
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["my-s3-bucket"]
    },
    "object":{
      "key":[{"prefix":"*/INPUT/*"}]
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: you're after some sort of "contains" matching pattern, which does not exist. Given that you're already filtering on a specific bucket name, adding `{"prefix":"MyFolder"}` should be sufficient IMO. Otherwise, reconsider the key structure

Answer (score 0):

If its not directly supported then you have to filter your events through a **lambda function**:

```
S3 ---> Lambda to filter the enents ----> SQS
```

Comment: yeah that is one of the way..but I don't want to invoke lambda for all the unwanted requests

Comment: @AWS_Developer Well, then you need to change your S3 locations, so that you don't need to use wildcards. The objects that you want to obtain events for, should have their own, dedicated bucket or prefix.